# Updating row in tables with huge amount of data

Tags: mysql

I have to update the `views` of the current `post`. From table `posts` witch have data > 2 millions. And the loading time of the page is slow.

Tables:

```
idpost | iduser | views | title        |
1      | 5675   | 45645 | some title   |
2      | 345    | 457   | some title 2 |
6      | 45     | 98    | some title 3 |
and many more... up to 2 millions
```

And `iduser` have **`Index`**, `idpost` have **`Primary key`**.

If I seprate the data and make a new table `post_views` and use `LEFT JOIN` to get the value of the views. At first it will be fast since the new table is still small, but over time she as well will have > 2 millions rows. And again it will be slow. How you deal with huge table ?

Comment: have you considered updating the value in an asynchronous call? this could help your page load faster.

Comment: I assume, you try to update the page views, when the page is requested. Instead, you could send an ajax call after the page is loaded to increment the view count.

Answer (score 1):

### Split the table

You should split the table to separate different things and prevent repetition of `title` data. This will be a better design. I suggest following schema:

```
posts(idpost, title)    
post_views(idpost, iduser, views)
```

### Updating `views` count

You will need to update `views` of only one row at a time. Because, someone views your page, then you update related row. So, just one row update at a time without a searching overhead (thanks to key & index). I didn't understand how this can make an overhead?

### Getting total `views`

Probably, you run a query like this one:

```
SELECT SUM(views) FROM post_views WHERE idpost = 100
```

Yes, this can make an overhead. A solution may be to create anew table `total_post_views` and update corresponding value in this table **after each update** on `post_views`. Thus, you will get rid of the `LEFT JOIN` and access total view count directly.

But, updating for each update also makes an overhead. To increase performance, you can give up updating `total_post_views` after each update on `post_views`. If you choose this way, you can perform update:

- **periodically**, say in each 30sec,
- **after certain update counts** of `post_views`, say for each 30 update.

In this way, you will get approximate results, of course. If this is tolerable, then I suggest you to go this way.